# How to catch "Nrpe unable to read output" when occured?

Tags: nagios, nrpe

I'm trying to catch "nrpe unable to read output" output from plugin and send an email when this one occurs and I'm a little bit stuck :) . Thing is there are different return codes when this error occurs on different plugin:

Return code Service status

0   OK

1   WARNING

2   CRITICAL

3   UNKNOWN

Is there a way either to unify return codes of all plugins I use(that there always will be 2[CRITICAL] when this problem occurs), or any other way to catch those alerts? I want to keep return codes for different situations as is(i.e. filesystem /home will be warning(return code 1) for 95% and critical(return code 2) for 98%

Answer (score 0):

Most folks would rather not have this error sending alert emails, because it does not represent an actual failed check.  Basically it means nothing more than:

- The command/plugin (local or remote) was ran by NRPE, but
- failed to return any usable status and/or text back to nrpe.

This most often means something went wrong with the command/plugin and it hasn't done the job it was expected to perform.  You don't want alerts being thrown for checks, when the check wasn't actually performed - as this would be very misleading.  It's also important to note that the Return Code is not even be coming from the command/plugin.

In my experience, the number one cause of this error is a bad check.  And as the docs for NPRE state, you should run the check (with all its options!) to make sure it runs correctly.  Do yourself a favor and test both working AND not working states.  About 75% of the time, this has happened because the check only works correctly when it has OK results, and blows up when something not-OK must be reported.

Another issue that causes these are network glitches.  NRPE connects and runs the check; but the connection is closed before any response is seen.  Once again, not a true check result.

For a production Nagios monitoring system, these should be very rare errors.  If they are happening frequently, then you likely have other issues that need to be fixed.

And as far as I can tell, all built-in Nagios plugins use the exact same set of return codes.  Are you certain this isn't a 'custom' check?

Comment: Problem is that I'm administrator of Nagios app, but I do not have access to all hosts on which checks are installed to debug it and find out what's wrong with the checks. I'm receiving config file with checks for specific host and uploading it to nagios server. That's the reason I'm looking for some way to catch these errors-then I can inform other people that they've did something wrong while creating these checks. I'm managing quite big environment and I don't want to verify thousands of checks manually everyday :)

Comment: I would test the checks in the config file before adding them, and remove any that are not working correctly.  Use the same approach after adding them.  A quick scan of the status.dat file will give you a listing of those checks that match plug-in output above.  Disable any checks you don't own that are failing.  You could also create a custom event handler for just these checks, sending emails and disabling them at the same time.

Comment: An event handler can be passed the $SERVICEOUTPUT$ Nagios macro, which would have the text you are looking for.  You could use this instead of $SERVICESTATE$ (OK, CRITICAL,...), to find the specific messages you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I've found the solution for my problems-I will try to check nagios.log on each node for those errors.